# Using a YAML header argument in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer

I am making a set of slides using `rmarkdown` and the LaTeX option of outputting it to `beamer`.

I have two templates I use in my slides - one specific for the LaTeX options, and one pandoc template that I have modified to account for some additional feature of my slides.

I have defined an option in the YAML header called `to_print` which is a boolean TRUE/FALSE that I pass to the pandoc template that tells it to add a package and clean up the slides for printing.

I also want to use this variable to define the name of the files. The basic idea being that I want to have one `.rmd` file for my slides, and then just changing this one option to signify that it's for printing by students, or for me presenting.

I have figured out that I can pass the `render` function using the `knit` parameter in the YAML header, but I have to specify `to_print = TRUE` and set the condition in the `ifelse()` statement in the output_file correspondingly.

Currently I have:

```
---
title: "Introduction to R"
subtitle: "Reading and saving data in R"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date())`'
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    fonttheme: professionalfonts
    highlight: tango
    includes:
      in_header: "../../templatefiles/beamer_header.tex"
    template: "../../templatefiles/beamer_template.tex"
    incremental: no
    keep_tex: yes
    slide_level: 3
    theme: Warsaw
    toc: yes
fontsize: 10pt
fontenc: T1
to_print: TRUE
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, 
       output_file = file.path(ifelse(TRUE,
                                      gsub("\\..*","_handout.pdf", inputFile), 
                                      gsub("\\..*", ".pdf", inputFile)))) })
---
```

I would like to specify just one parameter that is then used to signify if this is a handout to be printed:

Pseudo-code:

```
to_print: TRUE
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, 
       output_file = file.path(ifelse(YAML_PARAM$to_print,
                                      gsub("\\..*","_handout.pdf", inputFile), 
                                      gsub("\\..*", ".pdf", inputFile)))) })
```

Is this possible, or something equivalent that would let me have one `.rmd` file with a boolean to toggle presentation vs. printing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter()` function:

```
---
title: "Introduction to R"
subtitle: "Reading and saving data in R"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date())`'
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    fonttheme: professionalfonts
    highlight: tango
    includes:
      in_header: "../../templatefiles/beamer_header.tex"
    template: "../../templatefiles/beamer_template.tex"
    incremental: no
    keep_tex: yes
    slide_level: 3
    theme: Warsaw
    toc: yes
fontsize: 10pt
fontenc: T1
to_print: TRUE
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, 
       output_file = file.path(ifelse(rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(inputFile)$to_print,
                                      gsub("\\..*","_handout.pdf", inputFile), 
                                      gsub("\\..*", ".pdf", inputFile)))) })
---
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. More documentation about custom knitting is over here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html